# What is the standard procedure for deploying an MVC website with a team of programmers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I am used to working in a team that uses Web Forms and VS Source Safe, so procedure would be something like:

- get latest version at beginning of day and before checking out.
- check in all files at the end of the day, and notify team not to upload.
- when finished the page and ready to upload, take a backup, just upload your files and check in.

the team was small enough that it was manageable.

Since you precompile in MVC and Web Applications, it is not possible to upload the site whilst pages in development are checked in.

What is the normal procedure for deployment in small/medium/large companies?

Thanks.

Comment: We generally branch complete code to a release branch in source control and then get that code on a build server and do a publish (scripted or within visual studio) and upload the published files.

Comment: do you know any good tutorials to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no normal procedure, although by rule-of-thumb it generally gets more complex and convoluted the bigger the company.

Consider *your own process*, if there is nothing wrong with it, then don't change it.

If you need to expand your team, consider a more collaborative way to manage code and deployment. Deployment sucks and nobody wants to do it manually over and over, verbally telling people you're uploading and not to is even worse > consider a build server such as TeamCity or TFS and setup a deploy process that manages this for you.

Consider moving from SourceSafe to Subversion, GIT, TFS etc.

Research ALM across the web (there's lots of good shared knowledge on blogs), but again, consider your need first, and think about if any changes will be actually cost effective and gain you productivity.